# Trackpoint don't work after upgrade

Tags: thinkpad, 17.10, trackpoint

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad L570 under Ubuntu.

After the upgrade from 17.04 to 17.10, the trackpoint (little red button) and the 3 hardware mouse button don't work anymore.

I test it under Wayland and Xorg, same problem. I don't found any info of this kind problem on the 17.10 version.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: I don't have a solution right now. I hope some help from the community

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is taken by the bug #1731163.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1731163

I use this page to change the grub parameters and the solution work well: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters

Comment: Thanks. This makes the trackpoint work again. But I noticed that now the two-finger scrolling in the trackpad is not working. Do you have this problem?

Comment: Yes, same problem. So, I use the trackpoint with the middle click button(with the blue dot on it).

I hope a definitive solution with the launchpad bug. At this time, the workaround is better than nothing.